# How to measure a process with perf stat using its parent id?

Tags: perf

Is there a way to measure a process with `perf stat` using its parent id (something like `perf stat -ppid <pid> -e ...`)?

Comment: looking through the options, it doesn't seem to be a way to do that. Why can't you use `-pid` (which btw takes a comma separated list)

Comment: Well, unfortunately the child process id is unknown beforehand. That is why I am looking at the parent process. However in that case the measurement is not precise. So using the parent id for the measurement would be very convenient.

Comment: If you know the parent, can't you use `-i, --no-inherit child tasks do not inherit counters`?

Comment: I actually need the opposite of that. I want to measure only the child(ren) process(es) without the parent.

Comment: I see; need to think a bit more about this one... http://www.brendangregg.com/ is the place to look for information...

Comment: Any solution for this?